# localstorage getitem is not working on Firefox (version99.0.1), it return null

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

Local storage `getitem()` is not working while local storage `setitem()` is working and it only happens with Firefox. My assignment will be tested on firefox and required for `localstorage`.

js code for 1st HTML page

```
function studentinfo(firstname,lastname,studentid,checked){
    
    localStorage.setItem("Firstname",firstname);
    localStorage.setItem("Lastname",lastname);
    localStorage.setItem("Studentid",studentid);
    localStorage.setItem("Score",checked);
    localStorage.setItem("test","testlocalstorage");
    sessionStorage.setItem("session","testsession");
    console.log("test")
}
```

js code on 2nd HTML page

```
function getStudentinfo(){
    if(localStorage.Firstname !== undefined){
        document.getElementById("submitfirstname").textContent = localStorage.getItem("Firstname");
    }
    
}

function init(){
    
    // var result = document.getElementById("submittest"); 
    // result.onsubmit = validate;        
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Firstname"))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("test"))
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("session"))
    getStudentinfo();
}
 
window.onload = init;
```

the `console.log` for `localstorage` return `null` for both of them
`sessionstorage` is fine.

happy to share the full code if needed.

Thanks

Comment: _"happy to share the full code if needed"_ - An actual [mcve] (with proper indendation) would be more helpful. When and how is `studentinfo()` executed? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Works with latest FF (v99.0.1) -> https://jsbin.com/vegesigudo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: **the console.log for localstorage return null for both of them sessionstorage is fine**. `localStorage` can be restricted by Citrix, Network, AppData-Settings and/or private browsing, whereas `sessionStorage` is more liberal.

Comment: @Andreas hi, thank you for answered, the function studentinfo() will be executed after the validation return true (all the question have been answered)